# Append sum to a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

In Pandas, how do I append a sum of all columns of a dataframe to the bottow row?

I tried:

```
new_balance_df = new_balance_df.append(pd.DataFrame( new_balance_df.sum(), index=['Total']))
```

which adds one NaN column and one NaN row.

Answer (score 2):

My long version:

```
s=pd.DataFrame(new_balance_df.sum()).T
s.index.name = pd.Index(['Total'], name=new_balance_df.index.name)
new_balance_df = new_balance_df.append(s)
```